# Qual método que posso usar para fazer um layout de ticket?

Tags: android

Estou em um projeto de estacionamento do qual é necessário a utilização de ticket gerado através de um aparelho bluetooth.
 minha dúvida é como posso fazer esse layout? quais parametros e métodos que posso utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este Layout te agrada?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É de uma biblioteca chamada [TicketView](https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView). Ela funciona apartir da API 15 para cima. Você só tem de adicionar no seu gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.vipulasri:ticketview:1.0.4'
}
```

E utilizar no seu Layout XML:

```
<com.vipulasri.ticketview.TicketView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ticketView"
        app:orientation="vertical"
        app:scallopRadius="10dp"
        app:showBorder="false"
        app:scallopPositionPercent="50"
        app:showDivider="true"
        app:dividerType="dash"
        app:ticketElevation="14dp"/>
```

A app na imagem acima tem código aberto e pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView/tree/master/sample).

Comment: valeu mesmo cara,agradecido!!